# Verify if a sql query returns any row in a .sh file

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm new in shell programming.

I've to verify if certain sql query returns any tuple/row.

If something`s returned then one action is made, else another action is made. Something like this:

```
 getResults(){
    getAnyResults=`sqlplus -s $MMUSER/$MMPASS <<!
    set verify off
    set heading off
    set feedback off
    set pages 0
    set pause off
    set linesize 2500
    
    select x, y, z
    from A
    where s = 'N';

    exit;
    !`
       }
```

I'm storing the query's result on **getAnyResults** variable.

If variable **getAnyResults** returns any tuple/row one action is made, else another action is made

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: I removed a blank that would have caused you problems.  What does `getAnyResults` look like when the query returns something? What does it look like when the query doesn't return something?

Comment: thank you. what do you mean by " What does getAnyResults look like..." ?

Comment: Would it make more sense to use a SQL COUNT function to get a result that's easier to parse?